# В терминале на MAC выдает ошибку при попытки скачать pip а в дальнейшем билиотеку

Tags: python, pip, pygame

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку pygame, и на сколько я знаю, что при условии того что у меня на компьютере стоит python третьей версии то pip уже есть.
Но я столкнулся с проблемой, что я не могу скачать библиотеку. На что мне посоветовали скачать pip что я тоже не смог. По итогу:

1.Скопировал URL: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

2. Вставил его в терминал curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py >
   get-pip.py
3. Ввел sudo python get-pip.py
4. Реультат:

   DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. 
   Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future 
   version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 
   support in pip, can be found at 
   https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
   WARNING: The directory '/Users/petr/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent 
   directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has 
   been 
   disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip 
   with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
   Collecting pip
     Downloading pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
        |████████████████████████████████| 1.4 MB 1.2 MB/s 
   Installing collected packages: pip
     Attempting uninstall: pip
       Found existing installation: pip 19.0.3
       Uninstalling pip-19.0.3:
         Successfully uninstalled pip-19.0.3
   Successfully installed pip-20.0.2
   Petr:~ petr$ sudo pip install
   DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. 
   Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future 
   version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 
   support in pip, can be found at 
   https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
   WARNING: The directory '/Users/petr/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent 
   directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has 
   been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If 
   executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
   ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help 
   install")

Подскажите как быть

Answer (score 1):

Пару советов:

- указывайте, по возможности, максимальное кол-во данных о ПК, ОС и пр., когда не знаете в чем проблема
- Оформляйте вопрос таким образом, чтобы отвечающий не пытался его прочесть, а пытался на него ответить(я подразумеваю то, что вопрос "легко читается")

У Вас стоит mac. Это - unix подобная система. В ней изначально предустановлен python, однако в большинстве старых(примерно раньше 2017 года) по прежнему стоит python версии 2

#### Что нужно сделать?

Для начала проверьте, может у Вас `python3` уже установлен. Для этого запустите `sudo -H python3 get-pip.py`. Если появилась ошибка о том, что команды не существует, проверьте, может `python3` не установлен в `PATH`:

```
sudo find /usr -name "python3*"
```

Если `find` не нашёл путь до `python3` установите его командой `brew install python3`

И затем `sudo -H python3 get-pip.py`

Если `find` нашёл `python3`, то добавьте путь до питона в переменную окружения `PATH`. Как это сделать написано, например, [тут](https://androidp1.ru/bash-kak-v-macos-dobavit-novuju-peremennuju-path/)

Comment: Оформление пытался исправить - оно едет ещё больше

Answer (score 0):

Не влезло в комментарий, напишу тут.

@Petr_Anisimov Доброй ночи. 
1. Вам необходимо обновить Вашу версию `python` с 2.7 до последней версии, так как с 1 января 2020 года она - дословно "Достигла конца своей жизни" ))). 
2. Так же ошибка сообщает, что папка `/Users/petr/Library/Caches/pip` не принадлежит или недоступна для записи текущим пользователем. Вам необходимо проверить права на папку. 
3. У Вас уже установлен `pip 19.0.3` версии. Он может быть успешно переустановлен, но я бы советовал его удалить, чтобы не возникало у Вас проблем в дальнейшем. 
После того, как Вы исправите первые 2 ошибки, у Вас может быть переустановлен `pip` на новую версию.

P.S. Так же советую Вам использовать IDE для работы с python, как один из вариантов - `pyCharm` и устанавливать уже все необходимые инструменты и библиотеки через него.